# Split each line by a delim read from another file and store all split word compounds in the result file

Tags: awk, grep, perl, cut

I want to split each line from file `names` by each and every delimiter from file `delim` and store the unique word compounds into result file `compounds`. Lines from `names` that were not split should be removed from the output file. There are only 4 delimiters:  `-'+`

**Important**: `names` file contains utf-8 encoded people names.

```
$ cat delims
 (space is here)
-
'
+
$ cat names
Tania
Günter
Abdel+Aziz
Abdel'Piza
Märie-Pierre
```

The output compounds file should be (ordering does not matter):

```
Abdel
Aziz
Piza
Märie
Pierre
```

Comment: Does this kind of questions suit unix.stackexchange or I should try luck on a more appropriate forum? What is it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an awk that allows extended regular expressions for the field separator, then you could do something like

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS=""; while((getline < "delim") > 0){FS = FS=="" ? $0 : FS"|"$0}}
    NF>1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}
' names
Abdel
Aziz
Abdel
Piza
Märie
Pierre
```

---

NOTE: it arguably would be cleaner to use a character set `[ '+-]` rather than the regex alternation  `|'|+|-` (and would also eliminate possible confusion over whether `+` is a literal or a regex quantifier). However it would require careful shuffling of the entries since `-` inside `[...]` is a range operator unless at either the start or end.

Comment: Actually the POSIX specification requires `FS` to be treated as regex if it contains more than one character, so this should work on any awk!

Comment: @Quasímodo thanks that's useful to know

Comment: Notice that this does not yet remove duplicates from the output; in order to avoid an external call you may want to replace the `print $i` by `if (!seen[$i]++) {print $i}`. Also, on GNU Awk and Nawk it is possible to get rid of the `getline` call by supplying both files as arguments to `awk` (`delims` first, `names` second) and stating `NR==FNR {FS=(FS==""?$0:FS"|"$0)}` and then `(NR>FNR && NF>1) { ... }`. This is less portable, though (won't work on `mawk`, e.g.)

Comment: Assuming the intent here is to have FS created dynamically from whatever subset of the 4 possible chars is in `delims` then that won't work if a) delims only contains a single line containing a blank char as then `FS` will be set to the default which means fields are separated by chains of contiguous spaces (e.g. blanks and/or tabs) and will strip leading/training spaces, or b) delims contains a `+` since that's a regexp repetition character and what that means at the start of a regexp or after alternation (`|`) is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Comment: Though this solution is much faster. How can I escape special characters if the delims charset is ` -;!.'()$` ?

Answer (score 2):

This will work robustly and portably for the 4 chars in your example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    FS = (NR > 1 ? FS "|" : "") "[" $0 "]"
    next
}
NF > 1 {
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
            print $i
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk delims names
Abdel
Aziz
Piza
Märie
Pierre
```

The complexity required here is because you have 3 metacharacters in your set of 4 delimiters:

1. `" "` which means "any sequence of spaces" in an FS,
2. `"+"` which means "1 or more repetitions of the preceding expression" in a regexp (undefined if it's at the start of a regexp or follows a `|`), and
3. `"-"` which means "a range" if it's inside a bracket expression and not the first or last char.

So you can't just create a `|`-separated list like  `|-|+|'` from the chars in delims as then the meaning of `+` is undefined and the meaning of `<blank>` if it was alone wouldn't be literal, nor can you include them all in a bracket expression `[ -+']` as then the meaning of `-` is a range of chars from `<blank>` to `+`, again not literal.

What I'm doing above is creating a `|`-separated list of bracket expressions `[ ]|[-]|[+]|[']` as that will work for any/all of the chars that delims can contain.

Comment: Actually, I happen to have 5 symbols in `delim`. ```$ xxd delims
00000000: 200a 2d0a 270a 2b0a 0d0a                  .-.'.+...
``` With this setup, your program outputs 45385 word compounds out of 45370 original `names` file (probably, the copies, which is not what I need). If I `dos2unix delims`, your program complains `tst.awk:2: (FILENAME=delims FNR=5) fatal: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[ ]|[-]|[']|[+]|[]/`. Hex dump of unix-converted delims is `00000000: 200a 2d0a 270a 2b0a 0a                    .-.'.+..`

Comment: If I manually delete the last (wrong; probably due to the original file was written in DOS - it's 2002 file) entry in `delims`, your program is identical with @steeldriver

Comment: You specifically said `There are only 4 delimiters:  -'+` and so the script is designed to handle those 4 delimiters. If that's not what you have then edit your question to fix your requirements and example. No, my program is **not** identical to @steeldriver's for the reasons I stated in a comment under his answer and reiterated in mine.

Comment: As you can see from the `[]` at the end of `/[ ]|[-]|[']|[+]|[]/` in the error message you posted, your input file contains a blank line at the end. That's trivially handled if that's valid input - just tell us what to do with it.

Comment: Yes. The task description is for 4 delims and I won't change it. Given that, it works flawlessly. Though I don't see where you have used this constrain. Anyway, your solution does seem more generic than the previous one. And I wanted to say that the _outputs_ are the same.

Comment: The outputs are only the same when run with some awks and with some values in delims for the reasons I mentioned. With a subset of values or with other awks the script @steeldriver posted will fail while mine won't. I don;t know what you mean by `I don't see where you have used this constrain`, sorry.

Comment: I don't see any `4` in your solution that would indicate that it expects exactly 4 symbols in `delims` file. I don't know awk, I started learning it a few days ago, but from the programming perspective, it's not clear why your solution won't work with, say, 5 delimiters.

Comment: It's not about the number 4, it's about the 4 specific characters you listed. Some different characters would need a modified solution as you found out when you tried it with 5 characters, one of which obviously wasn't included in the set I wrote my solution to handle. Different characters mean different things in different contexts in regexps so unfortunately you can't just handle them all one way and expect it to work.

Comment: For example, `^` in `/^foo/` means "start of regexp" while in `/[^...]/` it means "not\" and if you just put it inside a bracket expression alone `/[^]/` it's a syntax error so while `[+]` makes `+` literal, `[^]` is a syntax error so you need `\^` to make `^` literal.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`, `tr` and `sort`:

Caveat: We need to move the `-` in `delims` to the top or bottom of the file (or `tr` will think there's a range).

Get all lines containing delimiter characters with `grep` and replace all delimiters with newlines (get all characters in `delims` without newlines with `tr -d '\n' < delims`).

Pipe the result to `sort -u` to eliminate duplicates and redirect the output to `compounds`.

```
grep -F -f delims names | tr -- "$(tr -d '\n' < delims)" '\n' | sort -u > compounds
```

Output:

```
$ cat compounds
Abdel
Aziz
Märie
Pierre
Piza
```

Answer (score 0):

We first build a regex on the fly by quotemeta function which quotes all special characters and then join them by means of a regex OR `|`. We skip any lines in names that don't contain atleast one element from the regex. For the rest we split them on regex then print only the uniquified element one per line.

```
$ perl -lne '
    $re //= join "|", map { chomp;quotemeta; } <STDIN>;
    next unless /$re/;
    print for grep { ! $seen{$_}++ } split /$re/;
' names < delims

Abdel
Aziz
Piza
Märie
Pierre
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also ....

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=RS="";FS="\n"; getline;$1=$1;
       s=gsub("-","",$0);FS="["$0((s>0)?"-":"")"]";
       OFS=RS="\n"}
     NF>1{$1=$1; print}' delims names

Abdel
Aziz
Abdel
Piza
Märie
Pierre
```

Which sets `RS` and `FS` so that `getline` reads `delims` as a single `$0` and then recomposes it with `$1=$1` making sure `OFS=""` so we don't add any unintended whitespace.

Then we can do a little `gsub` jiggery-pokery with `$0` to make sure `-` only happens at the end of the character set (only adding `-` to the end of `FS` if `gsub` is successful and `s>0`) to give you the character set `[ '+-]` as `FS`.

Now we can set `RS` back to `\n` but we also set `OFS` to `\n` too.

Then it's just to business as usual wherever `NF>1` but because `OFS="\n"` we don't need to iterate over `NF` we can just recompose with `$1=$1` and `print`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get the pbm solved.
We first dynamically prepare the regex to select the line by enclosing each char within square brackets (char classes). Thus does away with having to place tge dash at a designated place.

```
re=$(paste -d '[]' /dev/null delims /dev/null | paste -sd '|')
dlm=$(paste -sd\| delims | sed -e 's/||/\n/;s/|//g;s/\n/|/;s:/:\\&:')
rpl=$(printf '\\n%.0s' $(seq ${#dlm})) 

sed -En \
  -e "/$re/ y/$dlm/$rpl/" \
  -e '/\n/p'              \
names | sort -u

Abdel
Aziz
Märie
Pierre
Piza
```